# Zucchini fruits / teeny holes on skin not leaves

Tags: zucchini

To beat the bugs, I planted the zucchini above ground in an unused water fountain the previous owners had.  Cement.  Used excellent bagged dirt.  Leaves are fine.  Fruit shaped and color fine.  But there are these teeny holes as small as pin holes.  Never, in 45 years of gardening, have I seen these,  I live in Wilmington NC.

Comment: Bugs with wings are not exactly going to be deterred by that planting arrangement....and that seems to be what you've likely got.

Comment: A photo would help

Answer (score 1):

Seems most likely this is "pickleworms" *Diaphania nitidalis* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphania_nitidalis from a brief search. An [alternate and more through site from the University of Florida.](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/pickleworm.htm)

Bore holes in fruit, flowers and stems. Laid by a moth so not going to be stopped by your planting arrangement. Go through multiple stages of growth, so holes likely to get larger as the critters grow. More of a problem the closer to the equator you are, but extending range over the course of the summer as they reproduce quickly and move north (or presumably south) over the course of the summer.